# Spring bean create exception on Linux

Tags: linux, spring-mvc, weblogic12c

My problem is very absurd but really I checked many times before I write here. I have a web application. We developed it with Spring 3.2 and we are deploying it on WebLogic. jdk version is 1.7.0_79 and WebLogic version is 12.1.x. I am using Windows 8 and because of security policies of my company  my computer is very slow and irritating (anti virus program, hdd encryption etc.). I decided to install Oracle Virtual Box and Oracle Linux 7 as guest OS on VirtualBox. I installed same version jdk and WebLogic for guest OS.

After prepared my dev environment I came across a deployment failure which says bean create exception (because of circular reference). I checked the code and I noticed there is really a circular reference. But when I build the project on Windows there is no problem. I compared class by class but there is no difference between two. For testing I removed Inject annotation from the field causing circular reference and I could deploy project. That is if I build same code in Linux I can not deploy it neither on Linux nor on Windows.

I extracted two war files and copied classes from war generated on Windows to other and it worked again. I know this is very strange but I tried every combination to be sure.